iOS StoreKit1 sandbox resubscribing always returns fail (but its not)
We've finished the code for auto-renewing subscription of our iOS app however we have a little problem.
In sandbox environment I subscribe trough the app. No problem here. Then I cancel the subscription in devices Setting. Then I open the app and click the Subscribe button. In this situation I always get a fail in the paymentQueue. But its actually succesfully completed because when I check it in the Subscriptions page (in iOS Settings) I can see it.
I have finishTransaction in all cases except for .purchasing.
Is this the expected Sandbox behavior or am I doing it wrong?
   public func startSubscription(for productType: MyAppSubscriptionType, completion: @escaping (_ receipt: String?, _ price: String?, _ productID: String?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
        purchaseRequestHandler = completion

       guard let product = fetchProduct(for: productType.productID) else {
            print("Product not available.")
            purchaseRequestHandler?(nil,nil,nil, NSError(domain: "MyAppStoreKitManager", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Product not available."]))
            purchaseRequestHandler = nil
            return
        }

        let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
    }

    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        print("Transaction state updated")
        for transaction in transactions {
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchased:
                complete(transaction: transaction)
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            case .failed:
                fail(transaction: transaction)
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            case .restored:
                restore(transaction: transaction)
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            case .deferred:
                handleDeferredTransaction(transaction: transaction)
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            case .purchasing:
                print("Purchasing...")
            @unknown default:
                print("Unknown transaction state: \(transaction.transactionState)")
            }
        }
    }

